# How to remove specific nodes in firebase real time database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

how do you remove an object in firebase without removing entire "simnumbers" child ? for example only remove "LAkUUug..."

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#delete_data for info on how to remove data. If you're having trouble making that work for your use-case, show the [minimal code that reproduces what you tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First, As per your comment you need to get autogenerated key**.For that :-

```
  public String keyval;

      FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("numbers-guess-...").child("simnumbers").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if (dataSnapshot != null && dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {

                //  for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                   // if we want to get do operation in multiple data then write your code here 
               //  }            


                        keyval = dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    //add code in case you not get proper dat from firebase
                }
            });
```

To remove value in firbase you need to use **removeValue() and as per my view you should use it with addOnCompleteListener().**

**Now, add that keyval as a key which you want to remove.** show below code:-

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("simnumbers").child(keyval).removeValue()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                           //enter your code what you want excute                     after remove value in firebase.
                        } else {
                            //enter msg or enter your code which you want to show in case of value is not remove properly or removed failed.

                           Toast.makeText(this, "Remove Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: how do I get that "LAkUUug..." ? its a autogenerated key

Comment: yeah @ronan I understood. show my recent edited answer. it will helps you

Comment: Here, we have talk about single value - "LAkUUug....." .So I have not taking for loop otherwise you can also take it.

Answer (score 1):

For deleting you have to use removeValue() method. You have to know the key value of the child otherwise u cant do it. lets say somehow you managed to get the key value which node you want to delete. then just write the code .

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("simnumbers").child("LAkUUug.....").removeValue();
```